# Adding s3 signed url in embed for a pdf doesn't work

Tags: html, pdf, amazon-s3, embed, pre-signed-url

The url which looks like 
`https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1/2/4/2018/26/pdf.pdf_1537903203247/V0/output/pdf.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q434A%2F200926%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180926T053715Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=f3996e2401e95e7ebd071187fd55ead39c5296b1cf4d968&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host`

Isn't getting displayed , however the url gets downloaded separately.I have modified the url here.But the actual url works and downloads the pdf if opened in a different tab. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The pdf which I fetch from a s3 signed url doesn't load in embed tag of html.However other local pdf files do.How can I get that to work?

Comment: In the S3 console, when you check the object metadata, does it show `Content-Type: application/pdf`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It is application/octet-stream, will it show up if it is application/pdf but I have another concern.I am uploading this file as chunks or multipart.I am not sure if I can do application/pdf and still be able to use multi-part upload.

Comment: Yes, you can.  That is done when the multipart upload is started.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot.I will try that and post it here if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Michael-sqlbot correctly pointed out. The content-type had to be application/pdf. Javascript code for reference :

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            region: 'ap-abc-1',
            params: {
                Bucket: BucketName,
                ServerSideEncryption: "AES256",
                ContentType: 'application/pdf'
            }
        });
```

It makes sense that the browser to understand that the url is actually a pdf, it's  necessary to add this content-type to it.However, I want to point out that for other file-types like mp3,mp4,jpg,png etc. this was not required in my particular case.Don't know if it is universally true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open pdf file in iframe then you can written base64 string from backend and then convert base64 string to blob url in UI.

```
let base64strds = 'base64pdfstring';
// decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
var binary = atob(base64strds.replace(/\s/g, ''));
var len = binary.length;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var viewers = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    viewers[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
}

// create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"               
var blob = new Blob( [viewers], { type: "application/pdf" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var objFra = document.createElement('iframe');   // Create an IFrame.
        objFra.style.visibility = "hidden";    // Hide the frame.
        objFra.src = url;                      // Set source.
        document.body.appendChild(objFra);  // Add the frame to the web page.
        objFra.contentWindow.focus();       // Set focus.
        objFra.contentWindow.print();
```

Comment: Hi Rohit,
Thanks for the comment, however we did not want to include any backend to the scenario.Thanks for the effort though.